# Json object using WebAPI controller

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am using webapi controller.I have to pass an JSON object from Java applet to web api controller. How to write a web api controller method to accept the JSON object

```
public test GetPo(int id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API uses JSON format as [default format](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization):

> JSON formatting is provided by the JsonMediaTypeFormatter class. By default, JsonMediaTypeFormatter uses the Json.NET library to perform serialization. Json.NET is a third-party open source project.

what you just do is to defined your model object which map with json:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    // More properties
}
```

And your POST method:

```
public void Post(Model model)
{}
```

Comment: Hi ,I have one doubt .How to call the Post method along with the JSON object...For eg:http://localhost/api/Post/1/2.  is not hitting the Post controller?

Comment: @user1400915: you should ask another question :)